# Which token is needed to send push notifications through POST

Tags: firebase, http-post, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up a REST API server that could send push notifications using Firebase. [Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) says this is a valid POST request, as a start :

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
{
  "message":{
    "topic" : "foo-bar",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}
```

However, I can't figure out which Authorization bearer is expected here. There is a ton of them on the firebase console, and I've tried each and every one of them, none work. They all result in 401 response.

**Where can I find the expected bearer for this request ?**

Thanks !

Comment: See this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

Comment: Thank you for the link. All of the examples are requesting to go through either Java, nodeJS, .NET, etc. Does it mean there is no way I can get a token through a web page just to test my requests with Fiddler ?

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to use [legacy protocols](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_using_the_legacy_app_server_protocols) to send push notifications. We just need the Server key which can be found in the Firebase Console.

Firebase Console > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging > Server Key

HTTP request looks like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<your_server_key>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "notification": {
    "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    "title" : "FCM Message",
  },
  "to": "/topics/<topic_name>"
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

Check [Server Reference](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server) for other APIs for server implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I'll consider it. But since Bob Snyder's link worked great, I think I'll go for that

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all go to [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and choose APIs&Services->Credentials. From there click on **+Create Credentials->OAuth Client ID** (Interface changes all the time so try to find this option). And then, simply choose **Add Key** and it will give you a json file.

After you receive your json file you can try what was given in this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server.

If you want to send request from **Postman** then you can try https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground. Register there with your google account and from available services select *Firebase Cloud Messaging API v1* -> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging*. There in the second step press Exchange authorization code for tokens. Finally, you will get your **Access and Refresh Token** there